# How can I checkout only modified files from cvs-server using tortoiseCVS 

Tags: cvs, configuration-management, tortoisecvs, wincvs

I need to checkout the files modified by developers. I tried Date command but it check-out the whole project. But i need only modified file for my patch with directory structure. Is there any way to checkout those files.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what precisely what you want to do here - if you really do want to checkout a new copy of the project which only contains the files that are modified relative to your current copy, then I don't think TortoiseCVS has a way to do it. In principle I imagine you could do it manually (e.g. checkout a new copy of the project, compare it with your existing copy and then delete any files which are the same), but it would surely be tedious to do for any realistically-sized project.

However I'm wondering if what you actually want is to patch a local checked-out copy of the files with the latest changes committed to the repository by other developers? If so then use the CVS "update" command, which will merge those changes into your local copies while still preserving any uncommitted modifications you might have there. (Be aware of any conflicts arising from the merging process - TortoiseCVS should warn you during the update, but they have to be resolved with manual editing.)